# Enforcing protocol conformity on 'class' objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to do something like this in objective C:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)sampleMethod;
@end

@interface SampleClass1 : NSObject
@end

@interface SampleClass2
@property NSMutableArray* array;
@end
```

And later when I do this:

```
[array addObject:[SampleClass1 class]];
```

This SHOULD give warning as the SampleClass1 does not conform to protocol MyProtocol. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you sure you want `[SampleClass1 class]` not `[SampleClass1 new]`? It is not possible to have class protocol in ObjC

Comment: Yes, I want to use [SampleClass1 class] and not new. Thanks.

Comment: you can have runtime check to throw exception when it does not conform to the protocol. but compile-time check is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of knew that but was just wondering if some body has some solution.

Comment: If you are wanting to add `Class` objects... the `Class` object for a given class does not conform to the protocols instances of the class conform to... my answer will work if you're intending to check instances of a class... what you're doing seems odd.

Comment: To summarize what I want: to be able to show warning when a class object is added by calling [SampleClass class] to this array if that class does not conform to a protocol.

Comment: I know.  I got that.  The weird part (to me) is that you want to do this with the class object and not instances of the class...

Comment: Because I will be instantiating these classes at runtime on different events but I was hoping if I can enforce some compile time rule on which classes can be part of this category.

Comment: Is the goal to *avoid* adding a class that does not conform to the protocol to the array? Or do you want to add *all* of the classes and only show a warning when one is? If it's the former, my answer below makes sure that only classes that conform will be added to the array.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, you'll have to add a class category to `NSMutableArray`:

```
@interface NSMutableArray (AddConformingObject)

- (void)addConformingObject:(id<MyProtocol>)object;

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (AddConformingObject)

- (void)addConformingObject:(id<MyProtocol>)object {
    [self addObject:object];
}

@end
```

And then just use `addConformingObject:` in place of `addObject:`.

Comment: I certainly don't want to that because that would mess all instances of the NSArray.

Comment: No it wouldn't.  It would only effect arrays in files that import this file... and it's not changing any of the existing behavior.  It's simply adding behavior.  You use a different completely different method...

Comment: Yeah I know...agree with you, really long day :).

Answer (score 0):

Every subclass of `NSObject` inherits the method `+ (BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol`. Therefore, if you're looking to simply add an object to an array if the class conforms to a protocol you can do something as follows:

```
if ([[SampleClass class] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(aProtocol)]) {
    [array addObject:[SampleClass class]];
}
```

It is good to note that `NSObject` provides both a class method and instance method with the following signatures `+ (BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol` and `- (BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exposing `array` as a property and allowing any outside code from adding any object, add an "add" method to the class that only accepts the proper objects:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)sampleMethod;
@end

@interface SampleClass1 : NSObject
@end

@interface SampleClass2

- (void)addSpecialObject:(id<MyProtocol>)object;

@end
```

The implementation of `SampleClass2` can add the object to a mutable array private property or ivar. This way, no client code can add the wrong kind of object.